# truffle command is working from c:/Users/{User} only ,but not from anywhere else

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I have setted up a private Ethereum network. I did not have admin rights, but I managed to install truffle as an administrator. Now when I am giving command-"truffle".It shows error -

'truffle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'truffle' command is only working from the directory: C:/Users/{User}.

Please help as I have been stuck on this problem for past 2 days. Any kind of help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add the folder path to the system environment path variable.  Here’s a couple ways to go about this.

https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html

[Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

Comment: Ok seems like I can add the path, but can you tell me where I can find the installed truffle folder. I installed truffle through npm. Also I read somewhere that it is not required to set the path for truffle manually.

Comment: Usually installers do the path adjustment for you if you’ve properly authorized it to do so.  I don’t know truffle or npm, but you might run a file search for `truffle` or `truffle.exe`.